# Returning to a specific place in a file after extraction of characters

Tags: c++, file

I have a question, after I loop on a file and extract several letters with a counter to know how many characters have been extracted how can I reposition my pointer to point back the first one extracted. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
int get_length(ifstream &inp,int &length){
  int columns=0;
  inp>>columns;
  length++;
  while(columns!=0)
  {
    inp>>columns;
    length++;
  } 
   if (!inp.good())
        inp.clear();

   inp.seekg(-length,std::ios::cur);
   return length;
}
```

For some reason its not going back the same length, it's getting it wrong by one, I've tried adding to length by one then writing that seek function I don't know what's wrong here, I'm questing if I'm using the seek function incorrectly?

Comment: The code increments `length` an extra time. If the value that's read into `columns` is zero, it should **not** increment `length`.

Comment: Is incrementing `length` taking the number of skipped spaces into consideration?

Comment: Read about `std::basic_istream::tellg()`.

Comment: @Galik thanks man ! that was my problem ! and thank you all for your efforts ! sorry for the horrible question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is this:
You are incrementing 'length' each time an integer value is read from the fstream 'inp'. Depending on on how many characters wide the integer representation is you will need to increment length by that amount. That and new-line chars and any other whitespace in the fstream.

If your test data contains:

```
10
11
12
13
```

Then by the time you read 13 you will have consumed 12 bytes of file data.
Your counter will have only incremented 4 times.

You could do this more easily and accurately by placing a call to

```
auto const position_start = inp.tellg();
```

at the start of your function and once you read the data you're interested in 'rewind' to the start position with a call to

```
inp.seekg(position_start, std::ios::beg);
```

Comment: thanks that was the problem, the idea of whitespaces flew right over my head

Answer (score 0):

'ifstream' is a specialisation of 'basic_ifstream', so 'ifstream::seekg()' takes an offset in bytes (chars). However, the formatted input (to an int) will advance the the current position by some number of bytes (0 or more) as it converts the input to an integer value. Use 'ifstream::tellg()' at the top of the function to get the current file position and another call to 'tellg()' before calling 'seekg()' to get the new file position. The difference in the two values will be 'length'.